# JDBC show rows count

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to print my rows count at the end, But it shows 1

```
    public void showRecords() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        while (result1.next()) {
            System.out.println(result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2));
        }

        ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select count(*) from mytable");
        int rows = rs1.last() ? rs1.getRow() : 0;
        System.out.println("Number of rows is: "+ rows);  //print 1

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:
...
Number of rows is: 1

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of iterations of the `while`-loop?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel maybe i don't know how, Can you show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Output: ... Number of rows is: 1

That's absolutely correct because the ouput of a count query like

```
select count(*) from mytable
```

would only contain a single row containing the total number of rows. For you to now retrieve that count you should make use of the `Resultset`'s getter methods as usual.

```
int rows = rs1.getInt(1);
```

To retrieve the count the way you wanted to; use the same approach with your first query

```
ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;
System.out.println("Number of rows is: "+ rows);  // should print the count
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the count from a `RecoredSet` always returns a value of `1`, i.e. the record containing the result of the query. You want

```
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select count(*) from mytable");
if (rs1.next()) {
   int rows = rs1.getInt("COUNT")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must read the value from the rowcount query, as it is a normal query. Like

```
rows = rs1.getInt(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The count(*) does not have a column name (or only a "generated" one that you might not know). Therefor you need to get the value by column index.

Additionally you need to call next() on the ResultSet in order to be able to obtain the value:

```
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select count(*) from mytable");
int rows = 0;
if (rs1.next() {
  rows = rs1.getInt(1);
}
System.out.println("Number of rows is: "+ rows);  //print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post about [retrieving query metadata without extra roundtrip](https://blog.jooq.org/calculating-pagination-metadata-without-extra-roundtrips-in-sql/), which is something people typically do to paginate their data. I really recommend you don't re-run your queries all the time just to count stuff.  A simple approach would be to use window functions, which are now supported in a lot of SQL dialects:

```sql
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () FROM mytable
```

Of course, since you're using low level JDBC API to iterate your `ResultSet`, why not just count things in the client at that point? E.g.

```java
try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from mytable")) {
    int i = 0;

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + i);
}
```